# How do I get my browser to say which one it is?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox

I have two browsers on my Windows machine: (1) Firefox and (2) chrome. In my case they look very similar except that Firefox can't display some pages directly.  Can I add a title-bar to my browser window that says "Firefox" or says "Chrome" to indicate which one I am using?

My current solution:

```
[Chrome]: menu ->  help > About chrome

[Firefox]: menu -> help > About Firefox
```

but this is tedious. Sure there are small differences in icons. But is there a way to have either browser to display name on the browser window?

Comment: Look at the (highlighted) icon in the task bar?

Comment: I have the same issue between Chrome, Brave and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in Firefox.  Right-click in the empty tab area and choose Customize Toolbar.  Then in the bottom left check the Title Bar box.

[image]

The standard Windows title bar is now visible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Between Firefox and Chrome, I use this to enable the traditional menu bar.

1. Right Click on the top of the firefox window
2. Tick **Menu Bar**

The menu bar is permanently displayed now.

[Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-menu-bar-firefox)